# Panel settings: System panels all aligned left

Tags: pi-2, system-clock

I mucked with my panel settings using a janky mouse, and somehow removed a setting that had my system (clock, wifi, sound, etc.) on the right, and the Menu + custom apps on the left. Now everything's aligned left.

How do I separate that panel and return the system icons to the right?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the Panel to get to Add/Remove Panel Items.

You will find a number of Panel Applets you can insert. One of these is a Spacer, which you can insert (or move) to a position after the Menu (or wherever you want the division to be). There is a "Stretch" setting which will expand the Spacer to fill the available space.

Comment: Couldn't find the Variable Spacer, but was still able to change the prefs on the Spacer to push it all over. Thanks!

Comment: There is a "Stretch" setting which will expand the Spacer